# Proper maps for connectedness

Tags: general-topology

A map $f : X \to Y$ between topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ is said to be *proper* if the inverse image of a compact subset of $Y$ is compact in $X$.

Does there exists an analogous concept for connectedness?

A map $f : X \to Y$ between topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ is said to be *????* if the inverse image of a connected subset of $Y$ is connected in $X$.

---

If such a concept does not exist or hasn't been studied much, is there a reason for this? Why in that case has compactness seemingly been deemed of more important than connectedness?

Comment: I would think it's a very rare property.  Something as innocuous as $f(x)=x^2$ on the reals fails it:  $f^{-1}(1,+\infty)$ is disconnected.

Comment: Yes, there is such a concept; it is useful in algebraic topology, start by reading [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-connected_space#n-connected_map).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes a map between topological spaces $f\colon X \to Y$ is called *monotone* if it has connected fibers, i.e. $f^{-1}(y)$ is connected for every $y ∈ Y$. (Similarly, $f$ is called *perfect* if it has compact fibers and it is closed and continuous. Such maps are proper.)

If $f$ is a monotone quotient map and $Y$ is connected, then $X$ is connected as well. Hence, if $f$ is monotone and hereditarily quotient, then the preimage of a connected set is connected. (Hereditarily quotient means that every corestriction $f\colon f^{-1}[B] \to B$ is quotient. Open or closed continuous maps are such.)

Comment: Great answer! Just to make sure, in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485889374), in the second paragraph after Proposition 2.2, the third sentence reads: "Since the inverse image, under a monotone quotient map, of a *closed* connected set is connected...". Since monotone maps have connected (particularly non-empty) fibers they are surjective, so a monotone quotient map is open and so it seems the emphasized *closed* may be omitted entirely. Is this correct?

Comment: @Arrow: I don't think so. Monotone map does not have to be onto, the empty set is also connected. On the other hand, quotient map is always onto. But it is not true that a monotone quotient map is open, so your map is not necessarily hereditarily quotient. But for closed or open set, the corresponding corestriction of a quotient map is quotient. So the closedness is used in the argument.

Comment: For many people (me included!) connected implies non-empty :)

Comment: @Arrow: Sure, that's a matter of taste. But a monotone map does not have to be onto, e.g. $\operatorname{arctan}\colon ℝ \to ℝ$ is monotone.

Comment: Dear @user87690, on a very related manner, could you please take a look at Engelking 6.2.23? The mapping $h(z)=g_2g_1^{-1}(z)$ seems to be undefined if $g_1^{-1}(z)$ is empty, and this seems to invalidate the proof. So it appears having (nonempty) connected fibers is crucial for essential uniqueness of monotone-light factorizations. What do you think?

Comment: @Arrow: I didn't have time to look to your former question yet, but it seems it is now deleted. Regarding your current question, $g_1^{-1}(z)$ cannot be empty since $g_1$ is a quotient map.