# Classifing functions with the property that the preimage of path-connected sets is path-connected

Tags: general-topology, terminology, convex-optimization, monotone-functions

Given two path-connected topological spaces $\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y}$, consider  a function $f: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ with the property, that the preimage $f^{-1}(V)$ is pathconnected for all path-connected $V \subset \mathcal{Y}$.
For example, all homeomorphisms and constant functions should fall into this class. Does anybody know a name for this class of functions fulfilling this or a similar condition?
I guess for functions from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, the condition mentioned above should coincide with monotonicity, and I was wondering about a more general case for other domains and codomains.

Comment: I do not think there is a name for this, cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440306/proper-maps-for-connectedness

Comment: Thank you for the link; I will look into it.